# Interact with third-party Android applications

Tags: java, android, android-intent

There is a ready-made application that works autonomously, i.e. performs certain actions based on user input, and outputs the result. It is necessary that this application perform the same actions, but on command from third-party applications and return the result to a third-party application. The third-party application should call Activity of my application, passing several parameters, my application should be activated, collect additional information from the user, call other activations, perform certain actions on the interaction with the host and send result to the caused the application. Approximately it should look like this:

```
third-party app: Activity1 -> Activity2 (call my Activity with params) -> Activity2 (recive result from my app, in focus)

my app: Activity1 - Activity2 (recive params, in focus) -> Activity3 -> Activity4 (start Thread) ->Activity5 (return result)
```

The mechanism of interaction should be universal, so that any third-party developer could interact with my application. The question is, how is it better to implement it?

The interaction comes to mind through Broadcasts. The third-party application sends Broadcast, I receive it in my application, and I call Activity2 with the flags Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. My app perform the actions and Activity5 sends another Broadcast with the result, the third-party application is intercepting it from the outside. I do not know if this decision is correct, so I ask for advice. How best to organize it?

P.S. Ideally, the third-party application need to start my if it is not running.

Thanks in advance.